# How to find the Riesz representative?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I have the following problem: suppose we are in the Hilbert space $\Re^2$ and suppose $L$ is a functional such that $L\mathbf x=x_1$. I have to find and sketch the Riesz representative $u_L$.

Based on the theorem, I think that the meaning of this problem is the following: there exists and operator such that, given any vector in $\Re^2$, the scalar product $(u_L,\mathbf{x})=x_1$. Which means that it performs the projection of the vector onto the $x$-axis? P.s. I am new to functional analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $u_L=(1,0) $. Then $Lx=(u_L,x) $ for all $x \in \mathbb R^2$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Therefore what I wrote is correct?